# Link the api.ai agent to Facebook

Tags: oauth-2.0, actions-on-google, google-home

I am creating an api agent and I wanted to add functionality to the webhook to be able to talk to Facebook graph api. In order to do that, I want the specific intent to require a sign-in to Facebook before calling the webhook. That way it would have the token to make the API calls to Graph API.
Any idea how I can do that? 
I cannot find the authorization url, token url and client secret needed for OAuth linking.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have to own the OAuth endpoint for it to work with actions, so using the Facebook OAuth is not supported.

Comment: Thanks. But I was able to get it to work. Google does mention that any login url would work so facebook and linkedin had to work. I create apps on both facebook and linkedin which gave me the required oauth2 parameters to use. When I integrated it with google actions, it asks for facebook/linkedin authentication when needed.